# Is there an equivalent of CSS classes on controls in Swift and iOS?

Tags: swift

I have a lot of UIButtons on a view that have to be styled through code. I need to give them all rounded borders, which cannot be done in XCode's interface builder.

So I'm wondering, is there a way in Swift to style a whole bunch of elements all at once, like using a CSS class to style stuff on the web?

Each button has an IBOutlet in my controller and it would be nice to style them all at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"which cannot be done in XCode's interface builder"*.

Sure it can, but you need to consider the various factors which limit you to think in terms of CSS.

Design an extension to a UIButton. Then make it IBDesignable. If you want to actually see it in IB, make it IBInspectable. Maybe your code will look something like this:

```
@IBDesignable
public class Button: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable public var borderColor:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            layer.borderColor = borderColor?.cgColor
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable public var borderWidth:CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
}
```

In particular, pay attention to the cornerRadius inspectable property.

Finally [here's a link](http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/) that however old, I still find worthy of explaining things better than I can.